# How to specify adding classes

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to add a .trash class to every element inside a .secondary-images div, except for one .field--name-rd-page-secondary-image div.

I have tried this.

```
$('.secondary-images *').addClass('trash').not(".field--name-rd-page-secondary-image");
```

But it doesn't work.

Does anyone know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You had an error with functions order.

**`.not()`** function should be placed before **`.addClass()`**.

```js
$('.secondary-images').not(".field--name-rd-page-secondary-image").addClass('trash');
```

```css
.secondary-images {
  background: lightblue;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  margin: 5px;
}

.trash {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='secondary-images'></div>
<div class='secondary-images'></div>
<div class='secondary-images field--name-rd-page-secondary-image'></div>
<div class='secondary-images'></div>
```

Comment: @JonathanDalgaard Great to hear. Cheers (:

Answer (score 1):

Place the ".not" before the addClass:

```
$('.secondary-images *').not(".field--name-rd-page-secondary-image").addClass('trash');
```

Answer (score 1):

Use either:

```
$('.secondary-images *').not(".field--name-rd-page-secondary-image").addClass('trash');
```

```js
$('.secondary-images *').not(".field--name-rd-page-secondary-image").addClass('trash');
```

```css
.trash {
  color: red
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="secondary-images">
  <p>p</p>
  <p>p</p>
  <p class="field--name-rd-page-secondary-image">p</p>
  <p>p</p>
  <p>p</p>
</div>
```

Or

```
$('.secondary-images :not(".field--name-rd-page-secondary-image")').addClass('trash');
```

```js
$('.secondary-images :not(".field--name-rd-page-secondary-image")').addClass('trash');
```

```css
.trash {
  color: red
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="secondary-images">
  <p>p</p>
  <p>p</p>
  <p class="field--name-rd-page-secondary-image">p</p>
  <p>p</p>
  <p>p</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me too.

```
$('.secondary-images *').not(".field--name-rd-page-secondary-image, .field--name-rd-page-secondary-image .field__item, .field--name-rd-page-secondary-image .field__item picture, .field--name-rd-page-secondary-image .field__item picture source, .field--name-rd-page-secondary-image .field__item picture img").addClass('trash');
```

I have added extra items because i wanted to avoid all those too.

Answer (score 0):

You have to change your order

```
$('.secondary-images *').not(".field--name-rd-page-secondary-image").addClass('trash');
```